# crosscompile glibc for arm

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, glibc

Good day

Currently, I'm working on an embedded device based on arm-linux. I want to build GCC for my target architecture with Glibc. GCC builds successful, but I have trouble with Glibc build.

I use the latest version of Glibc (ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.12.1.tar.gz) and port for them (ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-ports-2.12.1.tar.gz)

my configuration line:

> ../../glibc-2.12.1/configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/anatoly/Desktop/ARM/build/glibc-build --enable-add-ons --with-binutils=/home/anatoly/Desctop/ARM/toolchain/arm/bin/

configuration script work fine, but i get some compile error:

> ...
>   /home/anatoly/Desktop/ARM/src/glibc-2.12.1/malloc/libmemusage_pic.a(memusage.os): In function `me':
>   /home/anatoly/Desktop/ARM/src/glibc-2.12.1/malloc/lmemusage.c:253: undefined reference to`__eabi+read_tp'
>   ...

I also tried using the old version (2.11, 2.10) but have the same error.

Does anybody know the solution for this problem?

Comment: .. you do arm _host_? I guess you want arm _target_..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a precompiled toolchain, like those provided by [code sourcery](https://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/codesourcery).
- If you want to make your own, optimised (premature optimization is the root of all evil), use [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/), which is a tool dedicated to cross-compilation toolchain building.
- If you are not convinced, and want to do everything with your own hands, ask your question on the crosstool-NG mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting arm-linux-gnueabi for arm-none-linux-gnueabi. Check that a compiler, loader etc. with the prefix you used for "host" exist on your path.